# How to get data from mongodb and display in ejs page

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am using mongodb and mongoose for my database. How can I retrieve data from mongodb using nodejs and display the contents in an ejs page? I have searched a lot and I still couldn't find the solution.

> This is my Schema

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

 var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

 var UserSchema = new Schema({

     username:String,
     _id:String,
     dateOfBirth:Date,
     telephoneNo:Number,
     address:String,
     email:String,
     fb_Id:String,
     jobTitle:String,
     password:String
 });

 module.exports=mongoose.model('User',UserSchema);
```

Comment: Can you upload your server or app.js code

Comment: The Plunker link is here   http://plnkr.co/edit/IjnLvScpcjpaiqcP2eBY?p=catalogue

Comment: Yes I tried. See in my previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41331781/how-to-retrieve-data-from-mongodb-and-display-in-ejs-page